# String (g)Match

Tags: lua, lua-table

Bom, estou querendo transformar uma string em tabela.
Tentei assim:

```
toset = "nb = 10, gb = 20, sb = 0, sfb = 0, ub = 0;"
toget = "nb = (.-), gb = (.-), sb = (.-), sfb = (.-), ub = (.-);"
t = toset:gmatch(toget)
for a,b,c,d,e in pairs(t) do
print(a.." "..b.." "..c.." "..d.." "..e)
end
```

Mas retorna esse erro:

```
[string "stdin"]:4: bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got function)
```

Alguem sabe resolver? Obrigado.

Comment: `gmatch` não funciona assim. Nem `pairs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você confia nesse string, então use

```
t = loadstring("return {"..toset.."}")()
```

Depois você pode verificar o conteúdo de `t` com

```
for k,v in pairs(t) do
   print(k,v)
end
```